# Why does "Stalking the Atomic City" use English units?

Tags: ukrainian-language, markiyan-kamysh, stalking-the-atomic-city

The following quote appears in chapter 4 of *Stalking the Atomic City*:

> Once, it was ninety-five degrees Fahrenheit, and my backpack weighed twenty-five pounds, on top of that.

Why does the book use English units? Is this just a translation choice, or is it like this in the original too?

Comment: What do you mean by "English units"? Fahrenheit was invented by a German and isn't much used any more in England or most of the English-speaking world.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes - why Fahrenheit and pounds?

Comment: But why do you describe these units as "English"?

Comment: @bobble As opposed to metric: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_units - although, technically, I should have referred to then as "Imperial"  or "US Customary Units", according to Wikipedia

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Even then, when you get to gallons, Imperial and US measures are quite different. And as for Fahrenheit, I assume the speaker is American (or possibly Francois Truffaut)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wasn’t able to find the particular passage quoted in the question in the Ukrainian original, but I did find this illuminating sentence:

> Тому і був потрібев надувний човен, і рюкзак під сорок кілограмів у прогулянку на місяць.

Translation:

> That's why I needed an inflatable boat and a forty-**kilogram** backpack for a month's walk. [boldface mine]

This shows that Kamysh did in fact not use English units in the original, so a choice¹ was made by the translator to avoid SI units in their² rendering of the text. Presumably because the publisher of the translation, Astra House, is based in the US, there was a choice made to change the units to something more familiar to readers.

And since the use of the term “English units” caused a bit of a kerfuffle in the comment section, the most accurate term would be British Imperial/US Customary, although most of the British Empire has completely gone over to the metric system with the UK itself and Canada having a mixed system and Liberia is transitioning, so the US stands out rather dramatically as the lone holdout sticking to the system, but thanks to its economic power, is able to cause measurement units to change in the course of translation.³

(The other non-metric country, although contemplating conversion, is Myanmar which still uses its [traditional measurement units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myanmar_units_of_measurement) which are defined in terms of British Imperial/US Customary.)

⸻

1. As a writer who’s written things that take place outside the U.S., the choice of units in my writing is something that I've had to give thought to in order to be fair to the work and the reader alike.
2. I use “their” because there are actually *two* translators listed for the book, one Ukrainian and one—I believe—American. I would guess the latter is responsible for the choice to de-metricize the text.
3. I don't remember if any distances, weights or temperatures appeared in the Harry Potter books, but I would guess that, just as the idea of a Philosopher's Stone was considered too abstruse for the delicate minds of American readers, any metric units that might have appeared would also have been modified for the sake of American readers. Thank heaven all the money was Wizard gold and the UK decimalized its currency in the 70s⁴ or there would have been even further complications for those delicate American minds.
4. Although, given how culturally conservative⁵ wizarding society is in the Harry Potter books, it does seem strange that they would have decimalized their currency along with the muggles.
5. I don't mean this in the sense of cultural conservatism in the contemporary political context, but more in the same way that say, the Amish are culturally conservative⁶, sticking to older ways of life and ignoring cultural changes as much as possible.
6. Betraying my ignorance about whether the Amish are also culturally conservative in the political sense.

Comment: I believe this is the first instance of a foot-foot-foot-foot note I have ever seen.

Comment: I’m clearly not someone who should be trusted with annotation capabilities.